# Cannot use import in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, import, module, importerror

I have a problem that confused me!
I am creating a desktop app based on javascript and HTML/CSS in the frontend and using [tauri](https://tauri.studio/en/) for providing Rust as the backend. the Tauri just provides backend and some works to app be able for running on desktop, and we can use what we prefer in frontend. so I use jquery as js library. it works with some js package managers like npm or yarn. I use yarn for it.

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM:**

In a piece of code, I need to import some Tauri modules into my script.js file.
but, there is some problem that I try to resolve them but they made me confused.

this is my script tags in the main HTML file:

```
<script src="../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="./app/Jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./chart/apexcharts.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

the `script.js` is my main js file.

**WHICH METHODS I TRIED:**

so in `script.js` I use import statement as below:

```
import { appWindow } from "../node_modules/@tauri-apps/api/window.ts";

const childwin = appWindow.open("new.html");
```

so the first error will show itself now:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

I don't know why this error, but I removed `{`s:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'appWindow'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

Oh God! what is it?! I search it, somebody says use `type` attribute in script tag. OK:

```
<script src="./script.js" type="module"></script>
```

result:

```
TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

damn! so I search it and some others say: oh, do you use type attribute?? go and remove it :(

and now I'm confused and I'm thankful if somebody help me :)

**EDIT:**
A friend said the problem is with the .ts file I am importing because the browser (or web engine) cannot support it. but I also try importing .js file and it leads to the same error too:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'loadReport'. import call expects exactly one argument.
```

Answer (score -2):

browser can't read typescripts `.ts` file. you must import the compiled version

Comment: He never said anything about TypeScript?

Comment: React file that imports in react components is also ts file. Does it mean React compiles ts files?

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT my imported file is .ts `"../node_modules/@tauri-apps/api/window.ts"`

Comment: @tpsp I try .js file  and it leads to the same error too :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).